# Hyperas TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm making this convolutional neural network that can detect between 4 types of images (for now its Cats, Dogs, Airplanes and Motorcycles which I use as test) and I want to optimize certain parameters using Hyperas. Now I'm only optimizing the Dropout rate, as a test.

I Keep getting this error however, and I dont know what it even means and what I can do to fix it.

This is my code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib.image as mpimg
 import os
 from keras import layers, models, optimizers
 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 from hyperas import optim
 from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe
 from hyperas.distributions import choice, uniform, conditional
 from PIL import Image as im
 from os import listdir
 from keras.datasets import mnist
 from keras.utils import np_utils
 from scipy import misc

 from keras import backend as K

 K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

 def data():

    tag_dict = {'airplane':0, 'cat':1, 'dog':2, 'motorbike':3}

    base_directory      = "."
    train_data_dir      = base_directory + "/Train"
    validation_data_dir = base_directory + "/Validation"

    maxsize = (100, 100)

    trainlen = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
    validlen = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])

    train_array = np.ones((trainlen, 100, 100, 3))
    train_tags  = np.ones((trainlen,))

    val_array = np.ones((validlen, 100, 100, 3))
    val_tags  = np.ones((validlen,))

    itemcounter = 0
    for folder in listdir(train_data_dir):
        for picture in listdir(train_data_dir + "/" + folder):

            tempdirec = train_data_dir + "/" + folder + "/" + picture

            img = im.open(tempdirec)
            img = img.resize(maxsize, im.ANTIALIAS)

            data = np.asarray(img, dtype='int32')

            if data.shape != (100, 100, 3):

                data = np.stack((data, data, data), axis=2)

            train_array[itemcounter] = data
            train_tags[itemcounter] = tag_dict[folder]

            itemcounter += 1

    itemcounter = 0
    for folder in listdir(validation_data_dir):
        for picture in listdir(validation_data_dir + "/" + folder):

            tempdirec = validation_data_dir + "/" + folder + "/" + picture

            img = im.open(tempdirec)
            img = img.resize(maxsize, im.ANTIALIAS)

            data = np.asarray(img, dtype='int32')

            if data.shape != (100, 100, 3):

                data = np.stack((data, data, data), axis=2)

            val_array[itemcounter] = data
            val_tags[itemcounter] = tag_dict[folder]

            itemcounter += 1

    def shuffle(array, seed=16):

        np.random.seed(seed)
        np.random.shuffle(array)

        return array

    nb_classes = 4

    train_array,    train_tags   = shuffle(train_array), shuffle(train_tags)
    val_array,      val_tags     = shuffle(val_array),   shuffle(val_tags)  

    train_tags = np_utils.to_categorical(train_tags, nb_classes)     
    val_tags = np_utils.to_categorical(val_tags, nb_classes)

    return (train_array, train_tags), (val_array, val_tags)

 def create_model(train_generator, validation_generator):

      model = models.Sequential()
     model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='tanh', input_shape= 
                                                         (150, 150, 3)))
     model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
     model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='tanh'))
     model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
     model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='tanh'))
     model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
     model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='tanh'))
     model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
     model.add(layers.Flatten())
     model.add(layers.Dropout(rate={{choice([0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])}}))
     #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
     model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
     model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

     model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                    optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001), metrics=['acc'])

     model.summary()

     history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=4,
                          epochs=2,
                          validation_data=validation_generator,
                          validation_steps=7)

     acc         = history.history['acc']
     val_acc     = history.history['val_acc']
     loss        = history.history['loss']
     val_loss    = history.history['val_loss']
     epochs      = range(1, len(acc) + 1)


     plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r-', label='Training acc')
     plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'g-', label='Validation acc')
     plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
     plt.legend()
     plt.figure()
     plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r-', label='Training loss')
     plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'g-', label='Validation loss')
     plt.title('Training and validation loss')
     plt.legend()
     plt.pause(0.05)
     plt.show()

     return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
 (x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = data()

 create_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)

 #if __name__ == '__main__':
     #train_generator, validation_generator = data()
     #best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=create_model,
                                      #data=data,
                                      #algo=tpe.suggest,
                                      #max_evals=5,
                                      #trials=Trials())

     #print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
     #print(best_run)
```

After running one optimization run, this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-33-df9a5e0e117e>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/lucky/OneDrive/Machine Learning/Crack_Net_5.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/lucky/OneDrive/Machine Learning')

File "C:\Users\lucky\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\lucky\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/lucky/OneDrive/Machine Learning/Crack_Net_5.py", line 161, in 
<module>
create_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)

File "C:/Users/lucky/OneDrive/Machine Learning/Crack_Net_5.py", line 157, in 
create_model
return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': create_model}

TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

I'm not running it with Hyperas yet
If anyone has any idea what causes this error and how to fix it, that'd be amazing!

Comment: For starter, you are passing generators to hyperas in `optim.minimize`, while the module probably expects something different. The  `train_generator` and `validation_generator` from the previous line are not used at all.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I changed the training data to a tensor of shape (3320, 100, 100, 3) and validation data (940, 100, 100, 3) instead of using the generators and still get the same error now. I'll edit my code in the post to what it is now.

Comment: @LukedeWaal , did you find a solution ?